# swift core data request comes up empty

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsdate, predicate

I am trying to fetch data from core data with predicate. I know that it is working when i am not using predicate. I am searching on nsdata so i first have to convert my string to nsdate and then use it to the fill the predicate. I have the following code that i use

```
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
let date = dateFormatter.dateFromString(workoutDate!)

println("Converted date to NSDate: \(date!)")

var fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Run")
fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "timestamp == %@", date!)

println("Predicate request: \(fetchRequest.predicate)")

workoutDetails = managedObjectContext?.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: nil) as! [Run]

for workout in workoutDetails {
    println("Fetched dates: \(workout.timestamp)")
}
```

When i read the println predicate request i see the following out put in the console Predicate request:

> Optional(timestamp == CAST(468347750.000000, "NSDate"))

After that nothing else is happing because it can't find what i am looking for in core data.

I am pretty new to all this. How do i get the proper entry by searching the timestamp in core data?

I have been stuck on all of this for the last couple of days.

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure that you have objects that occurred at this exact time? The `NSDate` class doesn't represent a date, it represents a single point in time.

Comment: When i do kot use predication I get the time stamp that looks like the date followed by de time with seconds and then +0000. That should be the date, the moment at that day is when a run is saved. I have followed this tut http://www.raywenderlich.com/97944/make-app-like-runkeeper-swift-part-1 this is all working, but now I am trying to get the details and coordinates of that run at that specific date. I thought I would do it like this, or should I do it differently?

Comment: Do the fetch without the predicate, then compare the dates of the returned objects (if any) with the date in your predicate. Do they match?

Comment: Yes they match, that is why I do not understand why it is not working. It looks like I am feeding it to the request. But the printing of predicate looks much different from what I put it, it are all numbers with a few zeros at the end. I have searched the whole web for a solution or something that can help me, but not much about fetching data.

Comment: When you say that the dates match, do you mean the dates or the actual timestamps?

Comment: the actual dates, i am not sure how a raw timestamp date looks like.

Comment: Don't confuse NSDate with the date (day) of the NSDate. The timestamp is the `timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate` method of NSDate.

Comment: i see yes, that must be the issue i guess. thanks.